# Jquery sort result not consistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, object

thats the code i typed in chrome console:

```
var o = { "B": "2", "A": "1", "C": "3" };
var e =  $(o).sort();
```

And thats the results (console.log)

```
Object {B: "2", A: "1", C: "3"}  //Output for: console.log(o);

// output for console.log(e);
[Object, jquery: "1.10.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
0: Object
   A: "1"
   B: "2"
   C: "3"
...

Object {B: "2", A: "1", C: "3"} //output console.log(e[0]);
```

can someone tell me how i get the sorted object, and why is the Object in e sorted and e[0] is not ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery won't apply a *sort* on a *normal* object just like that. Even if it abstracts the `Array.prototype.sort` method into its own collections, it doesn't work like that out of the box. jQuery expects *DOM nodes* to be in there, but even if thats the case, you need to at least define a custom `sort function` which you pass into `.sort()` to make it work.

You might know that *object keys* do not have any guaranteed order in ECMAscript. So we can only sort its keys "statically" as *Array* and then *access* the object with that sorted list of key names.

For instance

```
var o = { "B": "2", "A": "1", "C": "3" };

var sortedKeys = Object.keys( o ).sort();

console.log( sortedKeys ); // ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Of course, we could directly access the object invoking `Array.prototype.forEach`, like

```
Object.keys( o ).sort().forEach(function( key ) {
    console.log( o[ key ] );
});
```

Would output: `1, 2, 3`

Comment: that helped me a lot! thank you for this professional asnwer :) i will use 2d arrays in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special jQuery.sort method, it will use the standard javascript native `sort` function.
This one sorts arrays, you're trying to sort an object.

However, e still isn't sorted - it's the chrome console, which always lists the properties of your object alphabetically.

If you change

```
var e =  $(o).sort();
```

to

```
var e = $(o);
```

, the console output will still be the same.